# msqli query - mysqli_sql_exception syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hello everybody I have the following query that executed from phpmyadmin gives me no problem but while using mysqli extension is a nightmare, but only inside a function with variables.

```
$reference_field = 'attribute';
$value = $attribute; // it actual worths 'Size,S Small ,M Medium ,L Large ,XXL 2Xl XX-Large ,XXXL 3Xl XXX-Large ';
$original_value = md5($value);

 $SQL = " UPDATE jos_jf_content As j  SET j.value = '%s' ,  
j.original_value = '%s' WHERE j.reference_id  =%d  
AND j.reference_field  ='%s'  ";
echo $a=sprintf($SQL,$value,$original_value, $prodId,'attribute');
$Myconnector->real_query( $a   );
```

it's giving me

```
mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near " at line 3
```

Doing a print of the query seems all ok and executing it alone in a single php file to debug works fine, gives me this trouble only when inside a function

```
UPDATE jos_jf_content As j 
SET j.value = 'Size,S Small ,M Medium ,L Large ,XXL 2Xl XX-Large ' , 
j.original_value = 'f8508eb38ed3e26e6f3814a253b12c9a' , j.modified = 1331632841 
WHERE j.reference_id =1787 AND j.reference_field ='attribute'
```

Comment: I don't see any double quote in the result query. There is a chance you output *another* query

Comment: Inside what function? What does the function do to the query? Can you show us?

Comment: I can't believe the PHP code you show generates that query. `1331632841` is not an octal number and `1787` is not a binary number. Additionally, why use mysqli and avoid prepared statements?

Comment: Hi edited and corrected removing additional fields

Answer (score 0):

My educated guess is that you have something like this:

```
$bar = 'Hello, World!';
$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar='%s'", $bar);
```

... and transformed it into:

```
function get_sql(){
    return sprintf("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar='%s'", $bar);
}
$bar = 'Hello, World!';
$sql = get_sql();
```

Fundamental problems:

1. You haven't configured PHP to display notices.
2. You are ignoring variable scope.

Quick fix:

```
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

function get_sql($bar){
    return sprintf("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar='%s'", $bar);
}
$bar = 'Hello, World!';
$sql = get_sql($bar);
```